# What accounted for the Wanderer's lifespan?

Tags: a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In general, A Canticle for Leibowitz is known as science fiction and as I recall, it is a science fiction story: no magic spells, etc. But the Wanderer I think was supposed to be supernaturally old or there is someone who is mistaken for the same character by other characters many years apart?

Is it known that he really was extremely old and how is this explained?

Comment: https://www.shmoop.com/study-guides/literature/a-canticle-for-leibowitz/isaac-leibowitz

Comment: @Valorum Very difficult to read. The ads cover up text.

Comment: @Spencer - Adblock works a treat. I can't see a single ad on the site